# What is format of customs.json configuratin file?

Tags: netbeans

For my PHP project which uses custom HTML tags for template part of the framework I would like to define Netbeans customs.json file, which can contain these new tags. Empty file in nbproject directory called customs.json looks like the one below. Is there any descrition of what I can define and how in this file? (e.g. definition that some tag can be only inside of another tag ... something like TR must be inside of TABLE tag ... but for my custom tags ...)

```
customs.json 
{
    "attributes": {},
    "elements": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK there is no documentation, but easy way to add some definitions is to use custom tag/custom attribute in your HTML file, NetBeans will mark with error or warning with a bulb icon on the left of the line with the "error". Click on the bulb icon and IDE will offer you to define custom element, custom attribute, custom attribute on specific element etc. These action will add definitions to the customs.json file. Once you do this, they will also show in code completion together with common tags/attributes.

Comment: Its the way how I'm using it but cant see how to define the tag nesting requirements. I would appreciate at least some file sample with options available ...

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible

Answer (score 1):

You can check Netbeans sources to find the JSON keywords:

```
//json file keys
public static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String CONTEXT = "context";
public static final String DOC = "doc";
public static final String DOC_URL = "doc_url";
public static final String REQUIRED = "required";
public static final String ELEMENTS = "elements";
public static final String ATTRIBUTES = "attributes";
public static final String TYPE = "type";
```

http://hg.netbeans.org/main/file/tip/html.custom/src/org/netbeans/modules/html/custom/conf/Configuration.java

Comment: The link now redirects to Apache Netbeans' "Oracle Transition" page.  Any idea where this file is now?